# Euler’s (defective) proof for Fermat’s last theorem with exponent $n = 3$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

Euler's Lemma: If you wish to find a large list of cubes of the form $m^2 + 3n^2$, choose integers a, b at
random and set $m = a^3- 9ab^2$ and $n = 3a^2b - 3b^3$. Then $m^2 + 3n^2 = (a + 3b^2)^3$ is indeed a perfect cube.

However, in this proof Euler assumes $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$ is a UFD, which it is not so the proof is defective.

I'm trying to find a correct proof of Euler’s Lemma using $\mathbb{Z}[w]$,
with $w$ being a primitive third root of unity (solution of the equation $x^3 - 1 = 0$ different from 1, or equivalently solution of $x^2 + x + 1 = 0$), for the ring R above, in place of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$.

Would anyone know where I could find one or be able to give one? I have a pdf of the defective proof but am not sure how to attach it to this post. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: It’s unclear what this lemma has to do with it. This lemma, as you’ve stated it, is true whether $\mathbb Z[\sqrt {-3}]$ is a UFD or not.

Answer (score 5):

First let me make clear that Euler does not assume unique factorization in his proof. He doesn't even know (let alone define) what a prime number in the domain ${\mathbb Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$ is. Next this domain is almost a UFD in the sense that you just have to avoid elements with even norm, which should not be too hard.

This being said, Weil (in his book on Number theory. An approach through history From Hammurapi to Legendre) is providing the missing link by counting the number of representations of integers by the form $x^2 + 3y^2$. Proofs using unique factorization in ${\mathbb Z}[\omega]$ can be found in dozens of places (Edwards book on FLT, Ribenboim, Gauss's collected works and probably even her on MSE).

Proving Euler's Lemma is even easier; it is a simple consequence of unique factorization plus taking care of units.

Comment: seems I'm a little confused then... Would you know if theres a way to access the proof without waiting for a book to be shipped to me. I doubt my local library has it.

Comment: Prove Euler's Lemma using unique factorization. As I said, ${\mathbb Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$ has unique factorization when you restrict to elements not divisible by $2$. This in turn follows from unique factorization in ${\mathbb Z}[\omega]$.

Answer (score 0):

As you well know, Fermat’s equation can immediately be reduced to the case of prime exponent $p$, say $(F_p), x^p+y^p=z^p $, with coprime integers $x,y,z$. Two cases are usually considered, the first case where $p ∤ xyz$, and the second case where  $p$ divides exactly one variable, say $z$. For $p=3$,  we’ll simply mimick Euler’s proof, replacing $\mathbf Z$ by $\mathbf Z[\sqrt 3]$ . Usually this introduces difficulties because, after all, the simplest of all arithmetic rings is $\mathbf Z$ . Here a minimal amount of ANT will be necessary. But for $p=3$, things will work smoothly enough because we work with quadratic fields.

1). First case.  So consider the eq. $(F_3)$ with variables $x,y,z$ in $A=\mathbf Z[√3]$, which is the ring of integers of  $ K=\mathbf Q(√3)$ because $3≡-1$ mod $4$. The important fact is that $K$ happens to have class number $1$, i.e. $A$ is a PID (see the tables in [W]). Suppose in the first case that  $π ∤ xyz$, where $π=√3$. Since $π^2=3, π$ is a prime of $A$, with ramification index 2, i.e. $A/πA≅Z/3Z$, hence $t^3≡t$ mod $π$ for any $t∈A$. Besides, eq. $(F_3)$ implies that $x^3+y^3≡z^3$ mod $π^a$ for any $a$. Taking $a$ large, we conclude from the binomial formula  $(x+y)^3=x^3+y^3+3xy(x+y)$ that  $xy(x+y) ≡xyz≡0$ mod π : contradiction.

2). Second case.  This is notoriously more complicated. Let us first recap Euler’s approach to $(F_3)$ over $\mathbf Z$, with $z≡0$ mod $3$. Euler introduces the auxiliary equation $(E_3)  x^2+3y^2=z^3$, which he solves by working in $\mathbf Z[i√3]$, using implicitly what we call now the "principality" of this "ring".  This is incorrect, but fortunately the ring of integers of $\mathbf Q(i√3)$, which is $B= \mathbf Z[(1+i√3)/2]$ , happens to be a PID ([W]). Working in $B$, it can be easily shown that all solutions of $(E_3)$ are of the form $x+iy√3=(a+ib√3)^3$. Putting $u=(x+y)/2$ and $v=(x-y)/2$ , $(F_3)$ becomes $2u(u^2+3v^2 )=z^3$. Using $u≡0$ mod 3, Euler can perform descent on⎹ xyz⎹  and conclude. Here, let $L= \mathbf Q(i,√3)= \mathbf Q(ζ_6 )$, the 6-th cyclotomic field. It happens that $L$ has also class number $1$. Following the lines in 1), we can study $(E_3)$ and $(F_3)$ over $A$, carry on the calculations in the ring of integers of $L$, and conclude by descent.

[W] L. Washington, Introduction to Cyclotomic Fields

Comment: Euler was not "asserting without proof that this ring is a PID". He did not know what a ring is, he did not know what a PID is, and he most certainly did not assert what you claim he did.